# Text slide show not displaying

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a div that changes text every few seconds.  I'm trying to do this in JavaScript only.  I don't want to use jquery.  The console isn't showing any errors, and I made a few alerts to test where the disconnect is but cannot find out what i'm doing wrong.  Please help, and thanks in advance.

HTML

```
<div id="ss"></div>
```

JS

```
(function() {
  var UIlogic = {
    loadData: function() {
      var ss_i = 0;
      var ss_array = ["Reading","Redstone","Family","Engineering","Hockey"];
      var ss_elem;
      ss_elem = document.getElementById('ss').innerHTML;

      function ssNext(){
        ss_i++;
        ss_elem.style.opacity = 0;
        if(ss_i > (ss_array.length - 1)){
          ss_i = 0;
        }
        setTimeout('ssSlide', 1000);
      }

      function ssSlide(){
        ss_elem = ss_array[ss_i];
        ss_elem.style.opacity = 1;
        setTimeout('ssNext', 2000);
      }
    }
  };
  window.onload = function() {
    UIlogic.loadData();
  };
})();
```

Comment: Note that you never call ssNext function.

Comment: oh.... i thought i was doing that in the set timeout.

Comment: Take the single-quotes off the `ssNext`: `setTimeout(ssNext, 2000);` This means you're passing a reference to the function, whereas what you're doing now is like `eval(ssNext);`, which is nothing.

Comment: never call ssNext and ssSlide functions

Comment: You really have quite a few issues (such as, you can't store a reference to `node.innerHTML` and then use it as a node reference itself; `node.innerHTML` and `node.innerText` will give you a string, not a node reference, back). Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/n185zr1m/

Comment: on your last comment, i did not know that.  What should i do, drop the innerHTML part?

Comment: See the fiddle I added.

Comment: would it be possible to use this method with images also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never called your slide functions. Have a look at this to get started: http://jsbin.com/yutuji/1/

Answer (score 2):

1. if you want to call a function as a string in quotes you have to add `()`, I think - I never use it in this way.
2. Better do this **not** as String. Better is: `setTimeout(fct,100)`
3. There are scope problems. Define the textchange-functions outer of `loadData`